# HTML column next to each other instead listed

Tags: html, multiple-columns

I am trying to get an output of 3 columns next to each other. What I get is one column on top of each other. What am I missing in my code?

The input in between the [] is variable and comes from another page. This works fine.

It keeps saying that I have to add more information but I have no clue what I should add to make it more clear.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>MAINTITLE:: [TITEL] </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
                @import "assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css";
                @import "assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css";
                @import "assets/css/main.css";
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/js/page.default.js"></script>
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="top-bar">
                <div class="logo"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="title-bar">
            </div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 180px !important"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
         <div class="container">
               <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <img alt="300x200" src="[PICTURE]" width="300" />
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>
                                        [NAME]
                                    </h3>
                                    <p>
                                        [TEXT]
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?action=DETAILPAGE&id=[_ID]">Go!</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class row div around all of the columns. You have three rows that's why each column is on a separate row.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>MAINTITLE:: [TITEL] </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css";
            @import "assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css";
            @import "assets/css/main.css";
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/js/page.default.js"></script>
        </script>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="top-bar">
            <div class="logo"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="title-bar">
        </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img alt="300x200" src="[PICTURE]" width="300" />
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="caption">
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                <h3>
                                    [NAME]
                                </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                <p>
                                    [TEXT]
                                </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-1">
                                <p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?action=DETAILPAGE&id=[_ID]">Go!</a>
                                </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>


            </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you maybe help me where I should open and close this class in this specific code? Because I tried to open it before all the columns, and close it on the end, but without a result.

Comment: I still see them on top of each other instead of next to each other. As well the background and title-bar are not visible.